# Nginx response headers in html body and single HTML page having content from multiple HTML pages

Tags: html, angularjs, nginx, webpack

Nginx is giving weird file contents. That's why I am getting to see Nginx response headers in the body of the HTML page sometimes.

See the screenshots below. The first line has content from main.html, in the middle Nginx response headers, and the last line has the content from business-frame.html. This causes the browser to show a weird page consisting of response headers.

But when I open the same resource in a new browser tab, It's absolutely fine.

I'm googling it for many days with different keywords. But no luck.

FYI, This project uses AngularJS latest version, webpack@4 with gzip compression enabled to reduce the overload of NGINX, NGINX 1.10 with gzip compression enabled.

[Example of how weird the page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qs37.png)

[image]

[Network tab when the problem occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOJdF.png)

[image]

[First HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf32P.png)

[image]

[Second HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRXVv.png)

[image]

[Response received pasted in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEsWp.png)

[image]

[File with problem opened in another tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o22r0.png)

[image]

**EDIT:**

This problem has not arrived for many months after updating Nginx. I'm hoping it's solved in the update. Maybe this was the bug in Nginx version 1.10.

Comment: This problem has not arrived for many years after updating Nginx. I'm hoping it's solved in the update. Maybe this was the bug in Nginx version 1.10. Anyone having this problem now also?